# iOS - Flip animation only for specific view

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, flip

i'm developing a game which contained some view (as memory card game) and i want that when the user tap on a card this flip and shows another view. I use this code :

```
- (void)flipCard:(id)sender {

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    UIView *view=[btn superview];
    UIView *flipView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[view frame]];
    [flipView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [[flipView layer] setCornerRadius:10];

    NSLog(@"Flip card : view frame = %f, %f",view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y);

    [UIView transitionFromView:view toView:flipView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];

}
```

Every view has a transparent button which cover the entire view, so when user tap on a view is as tap the button. The button call the method above passing the sender.
When the animation starts all view is flipped, not only the view i get from sender.
How can i do?

Comment: Maybe not a direct solution but, you may try to extend UIButton for the buttons you used on the cards and have a weak pointer back to the card's view, therefore calling btn.cardView would definitely get you the view of the card that you have wanted, if superview does not works.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The following code might help with your problem. I think it is cleaner than using a transparent button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    flipped = NO;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

    [flipContainerView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [UIView transitionWithView:flipContainerView
                          duration:1
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:^{

            if (!flipped) {
                [frontCard setHidden:YES];
                [flipContainerView addSubview:backCard.view]; //or unhide it.
                flipped = YES;
            } else {
                [frontCard setHidden:NO];
                [backCard removeFromSuperview]; //or hide it.
            }

        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing `setHidden` and `addSubview` techniques: that's not consistent and one time there will be one subview in the container, the other time two subviews. I recommend to stick to one technique: either both front and back are switched with `setHidden`, or both front and back are switched with `removeFromSuperview`.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. After searching different posts on the internet I was able to come up with an elegant and easy solution. I have the cards as custom UIButtons. In the custom UIButton class I added the method which changes the background image with a flip animation:

```
-(void) flipCard{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self
                      duration:0.3f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                    animations:^{
                        if (self.isFlipped) {
                            [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"card_back_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        }else{
                            [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.cardName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        }
                    } completion:NULL];
    self.isFlipped = !self.isFlipped;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else as the first answer has been already accepted

**UPDATE**

If you are on the view containing this sub-view the code is:

```
-(void)flipCard:(APCard*)card{
    [UIView transitionWithView:card
                      duration:kFlipTime
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                    animations:^{
                        if (card.isFlipped) {
                            [card setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"card_back_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        }else{
                            [card setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:card.cardName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             //DO Stuff
                         }
                     }
    ];
    card.isFlipped = !card.isFlipped;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My use case in Swift 4:

```
@IBAction func flipCard() {
                let transitionOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromRight, .showHideTransitionViews]

        UIView.transition(with: letterView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
            if self.showingBack == true {
                self.letterImage.image = UIImage.init(named: self.letterImageName + ".png")
                self.letterNameLabel.text = self.regularWord
                self.showingBack = false
            } else {
                self.letterImage.image = UIImage.init(named: self.letterImageName + "C.png")
                self.letterNameLabel.text = self.cursiveWord
                self.showingBack = true
            }
        })
    }
```