# Different animation styles like flipboard animations

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I am new to ios development. i want different animation styles like  flipboard animations.can any one give me some sample examples.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flip between views like FlipBoard Animation in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947925/how-to-flip-between-views-like-flipboard-animation-in-ios)

Comment: i need other animations examples

Comment: other than flip and fold animations,can any one give  other animation names i.e animation list

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience in this, but after reading the docs, I think you're going to need a library for that. A quick Google search suggested:

- [Canvas](http://canvaspod.io/) (provides animations: bounce, slide, fade, fun)
- [MZFormSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController)
- [Pop](https://code.facebook.com/posts/234067533455773/introducing-pop-the-animation-engine-behind-paper/)

If you want to code your own custom animation, it appears that the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html) explains how.

Comment: Thanks @Will Sheppard

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library, but it is possible to transform the layer of a UIView in many ways, quite easily.

Say the view you want to animate is called `view` and is of type `UIView`

Here is how to animate it similar to a flip animation, where it rotates around the y-axis:

```
CALayer *layer = view.layer;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 0, 0, 20);

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 5.0 / -500;

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, angle* M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

The key function here is `CATransform3DRotate` which rotates the layer in 3d.

You specify the axis around which to rotate with the last 3 parameters (x, y, z) which is (0,1,0) in this case, i.e. the y-axis.

Note that this won't produce an animation, but rather, will orient the layer using the provided axis and `angle`.

To animate the layer, you will have to incrementally change the `angle`, in another function (e.g. using `NSTimer`).